# what was the world population around 1880?

Tags: population

presuming a population of 1,265,000,000 in 1850 and 1,656,000,000 in 1900 based off *[prb.org](https://www.prb.org/howmanypeoplehaveeverlivedonearth/)* what would be the most likely accurate estimate for world population size be in 1880?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimates_of_historical_world_population

Comment: Underneath the assumption of exponential growth (known to be reasonable during the 19th century), those two data points would be sufficient to (approximately) answer the question.

Comment: This is really a statistics question.

Comment: @Spencer - No. That's an historical question that could be answered using statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple linear interpolation would produce an estimate of 1,499,000,000.

1,265,000,000 +3/5*(1,656,000,000-1,265,000,000) = 1,499,600,000

Since we only have 4 significant figures in the input data, and an  exponential curve is going to be a little under a straight line, we should round down the 6.

Comment: Darn, no MathJax in History SE.

Comment: I get 1,487,000,000 when I do the exponential calculation, but it is hard to take such numbers seriously.